# How to trigger a cloud function when sending a firebase cloud message?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm trying to trigger a firebase cloud functions once a user creates a new firebase cloud message(FCM).

This [documentation page](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/manage-topics) describes exactly what to do.

Here's my code on the server side :

Side Note: *subscribeToTopic* can take one token or an array of tokens.

```
admin.messaging().subscribeToTopic(fcmToken, "/topics/news")
.then(res => {
    console.log('res: ', res);
})
.catch(error =>{
    console.log('error: ', error);
});
```

Assume fcmToken is a valid token, created from my device(client-side), i double checked it.

Now, to test if it works: I create a new notification using the notification web console provided by firebase, and after choosing title and body, i get to choose the topic like in the image.
[image: choosing a topic for the message]

**The problem is that the cloud function is not getting triggered at all.**

Comment: I think you might be mistaken what `subscribeToTopic` does.  It basically forces some client apps, identified by their tokens, to be subscribed to the given topic.  It doesn't arrange for any future code to be run on your server side.

Answer (score 2):

According to the documentation (https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/) there isn't a Cloud Function background trigger for Firebase Cloud Messaging (FCM).

What you could is to write in the Firebase database (Firestore or Realtime Database) in parallel to the message sending, and then use a `onCreate()` trigger for this database.

You will find the doc for the Cloud Firestore triggers here https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/firestore-events and for the Realtime Database ones here https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/database-events

Comment: nothing in the FCM web interface allows me to add anything to firestore or Realtime db once a message is sent, so the onCreate won't work.

Comment: Yes, this proposal is based on the assumption that the messages will be sent automatically, for example through another Cloud Function, which would allow to combine the two actions (sending the message + writing to the db)

Comment: I had that approach in mind, but it's not accepted, because as I mention, the FCM web interface looks nice and user-friendly.

Comment: In that case you will have to choose: either you can send a message through the Firebase console, or you can call custom code. There is (currently) no way to combine both.